# Adding active class on custom Magento left menu

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I've frankensteined a fairly nice menu for Magento. However I want to get some more functionality by adding a active class. Now, I'm not a php wiz, actually I'm not familiar with it, however with logic and trial and error I came a long way. But I think this might be either something small I already tried but didn't apply correct or not easy in this setup.

So, I'm looking for a way to add the active class to the `<a>` tag when the category is active, and/or child category is active.

This is how the menu how it works now:

```html
<?
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$subcatid = $_category->getId();
$parentCategory = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/navigation')->getCurrentCategory()->parent_id;
$name = $_category->getName();
$root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcatid); 
$subcategories = $root_category->getChildren();
$subcategories2  = $root_category->getChildrenCategories();
?>

<nav id="vert-nav" class="custom-left-menu" role="navigation">
<span class="menu-h3">
<?php $level = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getLevel();
if($level > 1){                 
    echo '<a itemprop="url" href="'.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName().'" title="'.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName().'"><span itemprop="name">'.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName().'</span></a>';
    }
    else{
    echo '<a itemprop="url" href="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'"><span itemprop="name">'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'</span></a>';        
    }    
?>
</span>
<ol>
<?php 
$_anyActive = false; 
foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); }
?>

<?php if($subcategories != "")
    {
   foreach ( $subcategories2 as $subCategory )
      {
      $subCategory->load();
      if( $subCategory->getIsActive() && $subCategory->getIncludeInMenu() )
         {
         echo '<li><a itemprop="url" href="'.$subCategory->getURL().'" title="'.$subCategory->getName().'"><span itemprop="name">'.$subCategory->getName().'</span></a></li>';
         }
      }
    }
else
    {
    $root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategory);
   $subCategories = $root_category->getChildrenCategories();
   foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategory )
      {
      $subCategory->load();
      if( $subCategory->getIsActive() && $subCategory->getIncludeInMenu() )
         {
            echo '<li><a itemprop="url" href="'.$subCategory->getURL().'" title="'.$subCategory->getName().'"><span itemprop="name">'.$subCategory->getName().'</span></a></li>';
         }
      }
   }
?>
</ol>
</nav>
```

So what I need is, that it adds the "active" class when a `<a>` tag is active regardless (preferably) if it is a submenu item or not.

I've tried a few things but I think due to the lack of knowledge I'm implementing things wrong. Can anyone help =)

*update*
Forgot to mention, it is magento, the page reloads when a link is clicked.

Comment: How does the category get activated? Click? Hover?

Comment: This line: `foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); }` should have to equal signs `$_anyActive == $_anyActive` but i don't know where you are getting this value and why you are comparing it to itself. That will always be true.

Comment: by click it is activated, like i said i frankensteined it =) so some things might not be right and could be removed, all i know is, that it works pretty descent and does what i would like it to do. Ill look into that part and let you know if i can find anything

Comment: `$this->isCategoryActive($_category);` is this how you get if the category was clicked/is active?

Comment: not sure, but it seems so